# uncaught exception with dictionnary and label.text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

I try to search in the dictionnary (passed trough an observer):

```
NSDictionary *myDictionnary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"details",@"details de l'installation",@"recapitulatif",@"recapitulatif de l'installe",nil];
```

... to set the text in a label :

```
NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", recapitulatif, [dictionnary objectForKey:@"recapitulatif"]);
details.text = [dictionnary objectForKey:@"recapitulatif"];
```

But it make me an uncaught exception :

```
-[ThirdViewController objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b59c30
2012-01-09 15:07:13.179 emars[8185:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ThirdViewController objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b59c30'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb45a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01108313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb60bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f25966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f25522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   emars                               0x0000439d -[FirstViewController updateLabel:] + 134
    6   Foundation                          0x0002f669 _nsnote_callback + 145
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00f8c9f9 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00f0b93a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
    9   Foundation                          0x0002520e -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
    10  emars                               0x0000880b -[ThirdViewController connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 541
```

Thanks to help me, I don't understand my mistake

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole method :

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *dictionnary = (NSDictionary*)[notification object];   
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", recapitulatif, [dictionnary objectForKey:@"recapitulatif"]);
}
```

And the Observer is send from "ThirdViewController" class :

```
NSDictionary *myDictionnary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"details",@"details de l'installation",@"recapitulatif",@"recapitulatif de l'installe",nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LABELUPDATENOTIFICATION" object:self userInfo:myDictionnary];
```

Thanks again !!!

**EDIT 2:**

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *dictionnary = (NSDictionary*)[notification userInfo];
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", recapitulatif, [dictionnary objectForKey:@"recapitulatif"]);   
    NSLog(@"text: ", [dictionnary objectForKey:@"recapitulatif"]);
}
```

Give me

```
key: <UILabel: 0x4b2ff80; frame = (20 245; 280 133); text = 'Index du Compteur: 1 572,...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4b30040>>, value: (null)
```

and

```
text:
```

This should give me @"recapitulatif de l'installe", isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error you posted (but not seeing more of your code, which you should *also* post there), it appears that you are trying to do the `objectForKey` method on your `ThirdViewController` object (which is a view controller), not the actual `NSDictionary` you wanted to get your object from.

Make sure `dictionnary` is set properly when you are calling `objectForKey` on it.

Do this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionnary = (NSDictionary*)[notification userInfo];
```

instead of this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionnary = (NSDictionary*)[notification object];
```

I've linked Apple's NSDictionary [`userInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotification/userInfo) documentation for you.

Comment: OK THAKS, In fact, I have to pass multiple values in one observer, so I made a dictionnary in the ThirdViewController class (as you said) and I passed it trough the Observer. I catch it, and I make the objectforkey (please check the initial post)

Comment: Yes, just as I expected.. you were assigning wrong.  I'm updating my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks again but I don't see how it can help me. With your code I've informations about the application but I need to get values stired in myDictionnary from another class :-/

Comment: You can't call `objectForKey` on your `ThirdViewController` view controller.  What you really want to do is get the value of `recapitulatif` from the `NSDictionary` object you passed along in the `userInfo` of the notification.  That's what my answer above is trying to explain. I hope I understand your question correctly.

Comment: You understand well but I have "value: (null)" when I made the objectforkey method on (the "new") dictionnary (I've update the post)